# Is this the correct way to define the complex logarithm, log(z) so that it is holomorphic on a set H?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

if we set $H:=\Bbb C \setminus\{-ir:r \in \Bbb R, r>0\}$, and we wanted to define a complex logarithm $\log(z)$ which is holomorphic on $H$. Then is the following what we would do ?

We know that $\log(z)$ is not differentiable on the negative real line because the arg(z) is not continous on this line. We also know that $\log(z)=\ln|z|+iArg(z)$

So to define $\log(z)$ s.t. it is holomorphic on H we say $\log(z)=\ln|z|+i(Arg(z))$, where $Arg(z)\in(\pi,-\pi/2) \cup(-\pi/2,\pi) $ (i.e the angle goes from $\pi$ to $-\pi /2$ but doesnt include these points , then it goes from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi$ again not including the points).

Comment: I think the convenient choice is $-\pi/2<\theta<3\pi/2$.

Comment: You need $r\geq 0$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Do you mean we should set $|z|\geq 0$ ?

Comment: No, I mean you can't let $0\in H$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier oh , I only set H that way because this is a question from a past exam paper, it must have been a misprint .

Comment: @Szeto but doesnt defining $\theta$ that way mean it will go over the negative real line , I thought that we had to exclude that part of the plane to define a holomorphic log(z) ?

Comment: Maybe that was a tricky question and the answer was "you can't, as exp(z) is never equal to $0$".

Comment: @exodius The branch cut is up to our choice. We usually take the branch cut to be the negative real axis, calling the logarithm with this branch cut PRINCIPAL logarithm. But you are free to do sth new. Choose your own branch cut! If you have chose it to be the negative imaginary axis, then forget about the one on negative real axis. There could only be one branch cut.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier oh that's  a nice point Arnaud, so you're saying we cant define log(z) on H because one of the possibilities is log(0)=ln(0)+iArg(z) and ln(0) is undefined ?

Comment: @Szeto ah you see I didn't know that , in class we were not told about being able to choose your own branch point. Probably in an effort to simplify the theory as it's only Complex I

Comment: Yes, that is one way of saying it. Could be a typo as well, but then an examiner would have to give full marks for this answer no matter what.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I don't often chuckle on math stack exchange , but the glee I shall have if such a question comes up this year and I'm prepared because of your advice made me do so just now XD